# Trim &nbsp values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim, kendo-editor

I am trying to trim the text which I get from kendo editor like this.

```
var html = "&nbsp; T &nbsp;"; // This sample text I get from Kendo editor
            console.log("Actual :" + html + ":");
            var text = "";
            try {
                // html decode
                var editorData = $('<div/>').html(html).text();
                text = editorData.trim();                    
                console.log("After trim :" + text + ":");
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("exception");
                text = html;
            }
```

This code is in seperate js file ( generated from typescript). When the page loads the trimming is not working. But when I run the same code in developer tools console window its working. 
Why it is not working?

Adding typescript code

```
 const html: string = $(selector).data("kendoEditor").value();
        console.log("Actual :" + html + ":");
        let text: string = "";
        try {
            // html decode
            var editorData = $('<div/>').html(html).text();
            text = editorData.trim();
            console.log("After trim :" + text + ":");
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("exception");
            text = html;
        }
```

Comment: *When the page loads the trimming is not working* - we're going to need more info than that to answer this question

Comment: `&nbsp;` isn't actually white space. It's rendered as whitespace by the browser but as far as Javascript is concerned it's not. It's a string.

Comment: There is a kendo editor in the page. User enter some text and clicks on Save button. Then this javascript gets called. Basically this code purpose is to trim the trailing spaces and save.

Comment: Working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4v1kmc30/

Comment: @Rayon When I run this piece of code separately, it is working fine for me. But in application its failing. That is why I felt it is strange.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&nbsp;` becomes a [non-break-space character](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00A0), `\u00a0`. JavaScript's [`String#trim`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.trim) is [*supposed* to remove those](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-32), but historically browser implementations have been a bit buggy in that regard. I thought those issues had been resolved in modern ones, but...

**If** you're running into browsers that don't implement it correctly, you can work around that with a regular expression:

```
text = editorData.replace(/(?:^[\s\u00a0]+)|(?:[\s\u00a0]+$)/g, '');
```

That says to replace all whitespace or non-break-space chars at the beginning and end with nothing.

But having seen your comment:

> When I run this piece of code separately, it is working fine for me. But in application its failing.

...that may not be it.

**Alternately**, you could remove the `&nbsp;` markup before converting to text:

```
html = html.replace(/(?:^(?:&nbsp;)+)|(?:(?:&nbsp;)+$)/g, '');
var editorData = $('<div/>').html(html).text();
text = editorData.trim();
```

That removes any `&nbsp;`s at the beginning or end prior to converting the markup to text.

Comment: Your editorData.replace solution is working for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Sree: Great! I'm sorry to hear browsers are still getting this wrong, but glad that helped. :-)

Comment: you are using a last resolution RegExp method which is dirty, hard read & maintain, and requires explicit encodings of a targeted type of whitespaces. The solution you just down-voted - is native, universal, generic and clean; easy to implement, maintain and customize for browsers that don't support the trim method natively.

Comment: @BekimBacaj: You clearly haven't read (or at least understood) my answer above, and clearly haven't understood the comments on your answer. Well, unfortunately, nothing more I can do about that.

Comment: The terminology is being used and misused in all levels of publications. This " " is a whitespace, or to be even more precise, an interval, this should be trimmed. This "&nbsp;" however, is not a whitespace or interval, that's a whitespace character, or to be more precise that's a white character equal to T or any other nonwhite character. Therefore it should not be treated as whitespace interval, and therefore not to be trimmed.

Comment: @BekimBacaj: For crying out loud. Just *read the specification*. I linked it with that very purpose in mind. From the `trim` link: *"Let T be a String value that is a copy of S with both leading and trailing white space removed. The definition of white space is the union of WhiteSpace and LineTerminator."* From the Table 32 link: *"The ECMAScript white space code points are listed in Table 32:...U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE <NBSP>..."* Thus: `trim` is supposed to remove no-break-space. And it *does*, on browsers where it isn't broken. As I said above.

Comment: that's wrong interpretation "&nbsp;" is not the same as \u00a0.

Comment: @Bekim: To quote you: "Wrong again!" Here's another specification for you: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references, which says quite clearly that the `&nbsp;` is U+00A0. And proof that it's actually true in the real world: https://jsfiddle.net/nyd3yb0z/ And with that, I'm done. If you feel the need to post further FUD, please cite reliable references.

Comment: @Bekim: What utter nonsense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for this.  it works for me.  how would you change it to make it work so that this: "&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; hello &nbsp; world &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;" becomes: "hello &nbsp; world".  Thanks!

Comment: @Varun - `.replace(/(?:^(?:\&nbsp;|\s)+)|(?:(?:\&nbsp;|\s)+$)/g, "")` should do it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

To easiest way to trim non-breaking spaces from a string is

```
html.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ').trim()
```

Comment: This will remove spaces in the middle of string

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can use jQuery.trim()

> function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. [source](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

Answer (score 0):

None of these fit for me. What I want to do was to remove `"&nbsp;"` only from the beginning or the end of the string but not from the middle. So what my suggestion is.

```
  let ingredients = str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
  ingredients = this.ingredients.trim();
  ingredients = this.ingredients.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
```

```js
var txt = 'aa&nbsp;&nbsp;cc&nbsp; &nbsp; ';
var result = txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
result = result.trim();
result = result.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation has proven successful for me

```
s=s.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ').replaceAll('<br>', ' ').trim();
```