# Remove leading and trailing white space using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i remove leading and trailing white space using jquery for the text coming from backend(ATG BCC) in `p` tag or `span` tag?

```
<div class="specific-col type-specific col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <span class="js-truncate-text" data-max="54">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Processor Information&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done until now?

Comment: Where are you populating text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim &nbsp values in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387414/trim-nbsp-values-in-javascript)

Comment: $.trim() is function you need

Comment: It is better if you post your complete requirement why need something to be done, or at least what you have tried as of now.

Answer (score 1):

try using jquery `$.trim()` function as below:

```
var code = $(".js-truncate-text").text();
var a = $.trim(code);
alert(a);
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/x06nuzwv/1/